# Comparing Dates in Lambda Expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda

I am trying to compare a date to a datetime field in SQL.  I try this:

```
Dim entry = db.Tbl_Hydrations.Where(Function(x) x.Hyd_Create_Date.Date = _date1)
```

However, the error I get is:

```
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

On line:

```
If entry.Any Then
```

Comment: Just to make sure, what you want to do is compare only the "Date" part of the database DateTime field, not the "time" part?

Comment: Yes, because the time is 12:00:00.  For instance, `_date` = `9/18/2012 12:00:00 AM` whereas the database field, `x.Hyd_Create_Date` = `9/18/2012 06:18:55`.  I'm trying to get all items for the entire day, not any specific time of the day.

Comment: Does the best answer remain 'Seems like LINQ to Entities doesn't support the Date property. ' need to be updated for current framework versions? A search on 'lambda date comparison' brought this page pretty high on the gjuice but surely by now there's better practice to be had? thx

Comment: @justSteve You'd probably want to do something like this `SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", x.Date)`` to get just the date part.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466176(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like LINQ to Entities doesn't support the Date property. You could try doing a comparison between two dates as a workaround:

```
Dim nextDay As DateTime =  _date1.AddDays(1)

Dim entry = db.Tbl_Hydrations.Where(Function(x) x.Hyd_Create_Date >= _date1 AndAlso x.Hyd_Create_Date < nextDay)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will accept this so long as no one else submits a better answer.  I was hoping for a method that didn't involve additional variables.

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is splitting the database field into two fields, one for date part, one for time part.

Answer (score 1):

not sure of the syntax (not a vb man, but you can use [canonical functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.createdatetime%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

```
Dim entry = db.Tbl_Hydrations
.Where(Function(x) EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime
(x.Hyd_Create_Date.Year, x.Hyd_Create_Date.Month, x.Hyd_Create_Date.Day, 0, 0, 0) = _date1);
```

Comment: I am beyond this now so I can't test, but it looks good +1.  Thanks.